# Overload resolution with rvalue reference to const char *

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue, rvalue

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(const char * const &s) {
    cout << "lvalue" << endl;
}

void f(const char * const &&s) {
    cout << "rvalue" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "abc";

    f("abc");
    f(s);
}
```

Output:

```
rvalue
rvalue
```

Why isn't the output "rvalue lvalue"?

Comment: It's autocast: "Array to pointer decay". If type of `s` is `const char*` then outputs `lvalue`.

Comment: The "abc" literal has `const char[4]` type and casts to `const char*` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither the string literal nor `s` are pointers (they are arrays), so the relevant section of the standard is [conv.array]:

> An lvalue or rvalue of type "array of `N` `T`" or "array of unknown bound of `T`" can be converted **to a prvalue of type "pointer to `T`".** The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

Note that

```
char const *p = s;
f(p);
```

prints "lvalue," to show that this works as you expect for pointers.

**Addendum re: comment:** In the case of

```
char *p = s;
f(p);
```

which prints "rvalue" if the rvalue overload exists but does not cause a compiler error if it is removed, two other sections of the standard come into play -- one of which seems to prohibit the binding of `char*` to `char const *const &` altogether, and the other opening a window back in.

The first is [dcl.init.ref]/4, where it is stated that

> Given types "*cv1* `T1`" and "*cv2* `T2`", "*cv1* `T1`" is *reference-related* to "*cv2* `T2`" if `T1` is the same type as `T2`, or `T1` is a base-class of `T2`. "*cv1* `T1`" is *reference-compatible* with "*cv2* `T2`" if `T1` is *reference-related* to `T2` and *cv1* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv2*. (...)

It goes on at length about precise rules for reference initialization, all of which is relevant but unfortunately far too long for a SO answer. The long story made short is that a reference to *cv1* `T1` can be initialized with an object of *cv2* `T2` if the two are reference-compatible.

What this Legalese means for our case is that `char*` and `char const *` are not *reference-compatible* (although `char*` and `char *const` would be), because `char*` is not `char const *` nor is one a base class of the other. This restriction makes sense if you consider the following illegal piece of code that would be legal otherwise:

```
const char c = 'c';
char *pc;
const char*& pcc = pc;   // #1: not allowed
pcc = &c;
*pc = 'C';               // #2: modifies a const object
```

This is adapted from a similar example in [conv.qual]/4 that uses a pointer to pointer to demonstrate the same problem.

[conv.qual] is also the other relevant section that opens the window back in. It says in [conv.qual]/1:

> A prvalue of type "pointer to *cv1* `T`" can be converted to a prvalue of type "pointer to *cv2* `T`" if "*cv2* `T`" is more cv-qualified than "*cv1* `T`"

It follows from all this that `char*` can be converted to `char const *`<sup>1</sup> (which is reference-compatible with `char const *const`), which is why the code still compiles if the rvalue overload of `f` is removed. However, the result of this conversion is a prvalue, so if it is present, the rvalue overload is preferred in overload resolution.

<sup>1</sup> `char*` glvalue -> `char*` prvalue (by [conv.lval]) -> `char const *` prvalue)

Comment: Shouldn't `char *p = s; f(p);` also be "lvalue"? Why is it "rvalue"?

Comment: Because a `char*`cannot be bound by reference to a `char const *` (it would allow you to break const correctness). [conv.qual] applies, which first requires lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and consequently results in prvalues.

Comment: I'm not sure what const correctness you are referring to. `Type&` binds only to modifiable lvalues, but `const Type&` binds to everything. For example, `string s1("abc"); const string &s2 = s1;` compiles fine.

Comment: A `char*` cannot be bound to `char const *&` because this would break const correctness (it would allow you to obtain a `char*` from a `char const *` by assigning a const pointer to the reference, putting it in the `char*`). For this reason, `char *` and `char const *` are not reference-compatible as per [dcl.init.ref]. [conv.qual] enables a conversion from `char *` to `char const *`, and you could bind the result of that conversion to a `char const *const&`, but the result of that conversion is a prvalue, so the rvalue overload takes precedence.

Comment: The lengthy quote from [conv.qual]/4 is irrelevant; there is no multi-level pointer here.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I guess I confused myself there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`s` is an array lvalue (so is `"abc"`, for that matter - string literals are lvalues). To get a pointer, the array-to-pointer conversion is performed. This conversion yields a pointer prvalue, which preferentially binds to the rvalue reference overload.